# Action not available for UISwitch

Tags: ios, swift

I created a UISwitch on storyboard and tried to drag it to controller to create an action but there were only Insert Outlet / Insert Outlet Collection 2 options available?  Why did this happen and how can I create action for UISwitch? I am using Xcode8.1

PS: The UISwitch was added on a container view

Answer (score 3):

When "ctrl" + drag, you should see something like:

[image]

You should choose "Action" and let the event -which is by default- "Value Changed".

However, if you can't see this (and I assume you should, or there is somehow a problem), you can add an event programmatically to the switch outlet:

In `viewDidLoad()` method, you need to add:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    // ...

    mySwitch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(mySwitchTapped), for: .valueChanged)

    // ...
}
```

`mySwitchTapped(mySwitch: UISwitch)` method:

```
func mySwitchTapped(mySwitch: UISwitch) {
        if mySwitch.isOn {

        } else {

        }
    }
```